# Simplify code - Checking the first character in a string to match a list of characters

Tags: java, string, boolean

So this is my code at the moment;

```
public static boolean isValidPiecePlacement(String piecePlacementString) {

    if (piecePlacementString.charAt(0) == 'A' || piecePlacementString.charAt(0) == 'B' ||
    piecePlacementString.charAt(0) == 'C' || piecePlacementString.charAt(0) == 'D' ||
    piecePlacementString.charAt(0) == 'E' || piecePlacementString.charAt(0) == 'F' ||
    piecePlacementString.charAt(0) == 'G'){
        return true;
    }


    return false;
```

It works fine, but it is not efficient. I was wondering if someone knew how to do
this is a more efficient way? The code just checks if the first character is correct, which is characters from 'A-G'. It also has to return true. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`['A', 'G']` is a range of characters, so it can be simplified to

```
public static boolean isValidPiecePlacement(String piecePlacementString) {
    if (piecePlacementString == null || piecePlacementString.length() == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    final char firstChar = piecePlacementString.charAt(0);

    if (firstChar >= 'A' && firstChar <= 'G') {
        // make other comparisons
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

`char` is an integral type, so the numerical comparison operators like `>=` and `<=` can be applied to its variables/literals.

Comment: This works fine, I should have added that I needed to do this for the second and third character as well. However, the second character needs to be from 'A'-'Z' and the third from 'A'-'F'. I thought by looking at the solution for the first one I would be able to do the rest, however, your solution returns a final statement.

Comment: @goat updated, you can write other conditions under the if statement, or make it more complex within one condition

Answer (score 2):

`char`s can actually be used as numeric values. Behind each `char` is a decimal representation according to the [ASCII table](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjBwI-PpoHhAhVBYVAKHTQdArMQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcs.smu.ca%2F~porter%2Fcsc%2Fref%2Fascii.html&psig=AOvVaw37WgGQvOVTnQPE0yelzg9I&ust=1552641409169072).

The character `A` has decimal ASCII value 65, while `G` has value 71.

You can simplify your code to

```
public static boolean isValidPiecePlacement(String piecePlacementString) {
    char c = piecePlacementString.charAt(0);
    return c >= 'A' && c <= 'G';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex` for this, e.g.:

```
String regex = "[A-G].*";
System.out.println("Asdsd".matches(regex));
System.out.println("Bsdsd".matches(regex));
System.out.println("Csdsd".matches(regex));
System.out.println("Dsdsd".matches(regex));
System.out.println("Hsdsd".matches(regex));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Set` of correct first characters like:

```
Set<Character> set = Set.of('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G');
return set.contains(piecePlacementString.charAt(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return the following:

`return "ABCDEFG".indexOf(piecePlacementString.charAt(0))>-1;`

Answer (score 0):

We can use regex:

```
String regex = "(^[A-G].*)";
System.out.println("Adfgh".matches(regex));
```